# Flutter - iOS debugging crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm debugging my flutter app on **iPhone 5s** using **VS Code**  but it crashes and I don't know how to solve this errors:

```html
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 5s in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              40.7s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)                                     
 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                          58.7s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                       102.4s
Xcode build done.                                           524.6s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011408d1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011362b735 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011408d015 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
        3   Runner                              0x000000010f3b125a +[FIRApp configure] + 138
        4   Runner                              0x000000010f5837d9 -[FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin init] + 217
        5   Runner                              0x000000010f58360d +[FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 173
        6   Runner                              0x000000010f34d81e +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 126
        7   Runner                  <…>
```

> PS: I was native Android developer before flutter so I don't know how to debug iOS
>
> and I'm using Virtualbox on windows 10 for building iOS apps on macOS Mojave 10.14.3

Here's my `flutter doctor -v` result:

```html
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.4 at /Users/salah/development/flutter
    • Framework revision cc949a8e8b (3 weeks ago), 2019-09-27 15:04:59 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.


 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.5

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 5s • D5C44375-4AD0-499F-891B-A2CE044C2EA4 • ios • iOS 12.1 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: My app works so well on android devices.

Comment: If you go to the command line, navigate it to your project folder, and type `flutter build ios -v`, what does it return?

Comment: This is a crash caused by Firebase configuration. If you configure the Firebase using the .json file generated for Android, you'll also need to add the equivalent .plist  file for iOS. You can also configure Firebase programatically from dart which won't require any additional files.

Comment: Oh, thank you @danypata this worked well and my app works 100% now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only added `google-services.json` file for Firebase configuration for android in:

```
android > app > google-services.json
```

You need to addd `GoogleService-Info.plist` file for iOS Firebase configuration:

```
ios > Runner > GoogleService-Info.plist
```

Comment: It was answered before by @danypata in comments, but u are absolutely right.